# Is there a recommended list of libraries to be used along with React js?

Tags: reactjs

**Reference MV* Architecture using React js**

I understand that React is an View Engine and it still requires many other libraries like Redux..etc.

Is there a list of libraries to be used along with React to build a complete ecosystem like Angular ?

Answer (score 0):

The React/JS ecosystem has become so rich, you can't really decide of a set of libraries to use by default in every projects.
It really depends on your needs.

Many people choose to generally go with `react-router` for the client-side routing, `react-dom` to interact with the DOM, `redux` for the state management, and `react-redux` to connect your components to the redux state.

You might find better answers by looking at the code of these react boilerplates, some of them explain there choices: http://andrewhfarmer.com/starter-project/

Answer (score 0):

One of the key decisions in choosing React over Angular for us was that React is a technology, not a framework.

The ability to mix librairies to your needs **is** the big plus; there is no *best* list. As a quick example, `redux` makes tons of sense for us for the webapps, however it does not for the `react-native` mobile app where it may not blend well with the `Navigator` or may be overkill...